# Pandas convert dataframe to pivot table to show count

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How do I transform my df so that it becomes sort of a pivot table to show the count of each of Col2 for the user id:

I have a df:

| ID | Col1 | Col2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | A1 |
| 1 | A | A2 |
| 1 | A | A3 |
| 1 | B | B1 |
| 1 | B | B2 |
| 2 | A | A1 |
| 2 | A | A3 |
| 2 | B | B1 |
| 2 | B | B3 |

I want to transform it into where each cell is a count of the occurence of Col2 per user ID. I also want to add multi-indexing using Col1 on the column (Sorry can't figure out how to format it properly)

| ID | A1 | A2 | A3 | B1 | B2 | B3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try via `pivot_table()`:

```
out=df.pivot_table('Col1','ID','Col2',aggfunc='count',fill_value=0)
```

output of `out`:

```
Col2    A1  A2  A3  B1  B2  B3
ID                      
1       1   1   1   1   1   0
2       1   0   1   1   0   1
```

If needed:

```
out=out.rename_axis(columns=None).reset_index()
```

### Update

try via `assign()` and `pivot_table()` method:

```
out=(df.assign(Col3=df['Col1'])
   .pivot_table(['Col1'],'ID',['Col3','Col2'],aggfunc='count',fill_value=0)
   .rename_axis(columns=[None,None,None],index=None)
   .droplevel(0,1)
   .reset_index(drop=True))
```

output of `out`:

```
     A          B
    A1  A2  A3  B1  B2  B3
0   1   1   1   1   1   0
1   1   0   1   1   0   1
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked. Is there a way for me to add Col1 as another layer of index on top of the columns?For example, A1-A3 would be under Column A

Comment: @Yundengogo updated answer....kindly have a look ***:)***

Comment: This works great, thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Check `crosstab`

```
out = pd.crosstab(df.ID, df.Col2)
Out[157]: 
Col2  A1  A2  A3  B1  B2  B3
ID                          
1      1   1   1   1   1   0
2      1   0   1   1   0   1
```